# What does this undefined method/collection do in this static initializer?

Tags: java, static, initialization

I'm trying to understand what [ZXing's CharacterSetECI.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/common/CharacterSetECI.java) is doing in its static initializer

Specifically, I don't know how this is possible:

```
private static final Map<Integer,CharacterSetECI> VALUE_TO_ECI = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<String,CharacterSetECI> NAME_TO_ECI = new HashMap<>();

static {
  for (CharacterSetECI eci : values()) {
    for (int value : eci.values) {
      VALUE_TO_ECI.put(value, eci);
    }
    NAME_TO_ECI.put(eci.name(), eci);
    for (String name : eci.otherEncodingNames) {
      NAME_TO_ECI.put(name, eci);
    }
  }
}

private final int[] values;
```

Notice the use of **values()** in the first foreach, the method values() is not defined anywhere in the class. The closest thing to it is the **int array values** defined below it, but I think we can agree it definitely does not contain CharacterSetECI type objects.

When I try to type only this snippet of code in a new class (create a constructor, final instance variable array and the static initializer), Eclipse complains that values() is undefined, but when I copy the whole code into a new class, Eclipse simply complains that a few types cannot be resolved but the values() gets a pass. I tried to ctrl+click on the values() to see what it's referencing to but it's not clickable.

**Note**:

In case you don't trust links, this class is available in ZXing's source code for version 3.1.0, available in mavencentral, in package com.google.zxing.common.

Comment: `CharacterSetECI` is an enum... This is a standard way of caching information about the enums, for quicker access in `getCharacterSetECIByValue`.

Comment: Does an enum have additional rules for its static initializer?

Comment: No but it has a `values` method.

Comment: Well, I never actually thought that enum has everything to do with that. Can you please put that as an aswer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `enum` has an implicit `values` method; from [JLS §8.9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3):

> The members of an enum type `E` are all of the following:
>
> - ...
> - The following implicitly declared methods:
>
>   ```
>   /**
>   * Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
>   * type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
>   * used to iterate over the constants as follows:
>   *
>   *    for(E c : E.values())
>   *        System.out.println(c);
>   *
>   * @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
>   * type, in the order they're declared
>   */
>   public static E[] values();
>   ```